# Html not scrolling

Tags: html, css

So my page will not scroll. I've had a poke around with some research and tried to get rid of position:fixed but that doesn't seem to have helped.  Any suggestions?

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
height: 2000px
overflow: scroll;
}
#header {
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
width: 97.5%;
margin-top: 5px;
height: 60px;
background-color: #fffafa;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#footer {
clear: both;
position: relative;
width: 97.5%;
margin-top: 5px;
height: 30 px;
background-color: #ffc873;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.left {
position: relative;
margin-top: 70px;
height: 300px;
width: 20%;
background-color: #689ad3;
float: left;
}

.right {
height: 200px;
width: 20%;
margin-top: 70px;
height: 300px;
background-color: #689ad3;
float: right;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you missed a semi-colon after first declaration for the `body` tag: `body {
    height: 2000px;
    overflow: scroll;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Because of your css code.

```
height: 2000px
```

Get rid of it immediately

Comment: Thanks. Someone else suggested this as a solution to my problem - tried without. Still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this css:**

```
body {
height: 2000px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
#header {
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
width: 97.5%;
margin-top: 5px;
height: 60px;
background-color: #fffafa;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#footer {
clear: both;
position: relative;
width: 97.5%;
margin-top: 5px;
height: 30 px;
background-color: #ffc873;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.left {
position: relative;
margin-top: 70px;
height: 300px;
width: 20%;
background-color: #689ad3;
float: left;
}

.right {
height: 200px;
width: 20%;
margin-top: 70px;
height: 300px;
background-color: #689ad3;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I had a good poke around with overflow-y. Unfortunately I'm still not scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the issue was not in the CSS after all. The problem was that my django code wasn't looking for the CSS in the right place - once I moved the code to the correct static location the overflow-y solution worked like a charm.